# Validacion de intentos de login

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure

Buen dia, estoy creando un sistema con un login

```
CREATE DEFINER=``@`%` PROCEDURE ``(
IN PUSU VARCHAR(50),
  IN PCONTRA VARCHAR(50),
  IN IP VARCHAR(20),
  OUT PRESULTADO VARCHAR(20)
)
BEGIN
DECLARE CONTEO, CONTEO2, CONTEO3 INT;
/*CHECAR SI ES USUARIO ACTIVO*/
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO CONTEO FROM INHA_DET_CFGUSUARIOS WHERE CUSU_CUSUARIO = PUSU AND CUSU_CCONTRASENIA = PCONTRA AND CUSU_NESTATUSUSUARIO  = 1;
/*CHECAR SI ES USUARIO INACTIVO*/
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO CONTEO2 FROM INHA_DET_CFGUSUARIOS WHERE CUSU_CUSUARIO = PUSU AND CUSU_NESTATUSUSUARIO  = 0;
/*CHECAR SI EL USUARIO ES EXISTENTE */
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO CONTEO3 FROM INHA_DET_CFGUSUARIOS WHERE CUSU_CUSUARIO = PUSU AND CUSU_CCONTRASENIA = PCONTRA AND CUSU_NESTATUSUSUARIO  = 1;


IF CONTEO = 1 THEN 
SELECT US.CUSU_CUSUARIO AS USUARIO , USUROL.CUSR_NIDROL AS ROL
FROM INHA_DET_CFGUSUARIOS US
INNER JOIN INHA_DET_CFGUSUROL USUROL ON USUROL.CUSR_NIDUSUARIO = US.CUSU_NIDUSUARIO
INNER JOIN INHA_MST_CFGROLES ROLS ON ROLS.CFRO_NIDROL = USUROL.CUSR_NIDROL  WHERE US.CUSU_CUSUARIO = PUSU AND US.CUSU_CCONTRASENIA = PCONTRA AND US.CUSU_NESTATUSUSUARIO  = 1; 
UPDATE INHA_DET_CFGUSUARIOS 
SET CUSU_NINTENTOSLOGIN = 0 WHERE CUSU_CUSUARIO = PUSU;
SET PRESULTADO = 'OK';

ELSEIF CONTEO2 = 0 THEN 
SELECT US.CUSU_CUSUARIO AS USUARIO , USUROL.CUSR_NIDROL AS ROL
FROM INHA_DET_CFGUSUARIOS US
INNER JOIN INHA_DET_CFGUSUROL USUROL ON USUROL.CUSR_NIDUSUARIO = US.CUSU_NIDUSUARIO
INNER JOIN INHA_MST_CFGROLES ROLS ON ROLS.CFRO_NIDROL = USUROL.CUSR_NIDROL  WHERE  US.CUSU_CUSUARIO = PUSU AND US.CUSU_CCONTRASENIA = PCONTRA OR US.CUSU_CCONTRASENIA <> PCONTRA  AND US.CUSU_NESTATUSUSUARIO  = 1; 
UPDATE INHA_DET_CFGUSUARIOS 
SET CUSU_NINTENTOSLOGIN =  CUSU_NINTENTOSLOGIN + 1 WHERE CUSU_CUSUARIO = PUSU;
SET PRESULTADO = 'CONTRASEÑA';
ELSEIF CUSU_NINTENTOSLOGIN  <= 8
THEN SET PRESULTADO = 'NO EXISTE';
```

En CONTEO2 hago que se haga una update en la tabla de INHA_DET_CFGUSUARIOS en el row CUSU_INTENTOSLOGIN, cuando el usuario ingresa mal la contraseña. Lo que quiero hacer, y es lo que estoy intentando hacer, es hacer que esta seccion:

```
 ELSEIF CUSU_NINTENTOSLOGIN  <= 8
    THEN SET PRESULTADO = 'NO EXISTE';
```

Es que si el usuario ya intento 8 veces hacer login, brinque el error de NO EXISTE, sin embargo, me sigue saliendo el error de CONTRASEÑA, que lo podemos encontrar en esta seccion:

```
ELSEIF CONTEO2 = 0 THEN 
SELECT US.CUSU_CUSUARIO AS USUARIO , USUROL.CUSR_NIDROL AS ROL
FROM INHA_DET_CFGUSUARIOS US
INNER JOIN INHA_DET_CFGUSUROL USUROL ON USUROL.CUSR_NIDUSUARIO = US.CUSU_NIDUSUARIO
INNER JOIN INHA_MST_CFGROLES ROLS ON ROLS.CFRO_NIDROL = USUROL.CUSR_NIDROL  WHERE  US.CUSU_CUSUARIO = PUSU AND US.CUSU_CCONTRASENIA = PCONTRA OR US.CUSU_CCONTRASENIA <> PCONTRA  AND US.CUSU_NESTATUSUSUARIO  = 1; 
UPDATE INHA_DET_CFGUSUARIOS 
SET CUSU_NINTENTOSLOGIN =  CUSU_NINTENTOSLOGIN + 1 WHERE CUSU_CUSUARIO = PUSU;
SET PRESULTADO = 'CONTRASEÑA';
```

¿Como puedo hacer, que el Stored procedure revise los intentos que ha intentado acceder el usuario, y asi brincar el error de NO EXISTE?

Comment: ¿Podrías resumir brevemente la lógica que intentas implementar? Creo que lo primero sería verificar si el usuario existe y a partir de ahí hacer las otras verificaciones. Lo estás haciendo al revés y eso causa confusión en la forma de escribir el código.

Comment: Con el SELECT de CONTEO, valido si el usuario esta habilitado y pueda acceder al sistema
Con el CONTEO2 valido si el usuario escribio bien o mal la contraseña, lo cual salta el error de CONTRASEÑA INCORRECTA

Lo que hace el ELSEIF de CONTEO2 es contar tambien los intentos del login, y quiero hacer que si el usuario ya intento ingresar X cantidad de veces, salte el error de "Usuario Bloqueado"

Comment: Eso no resume la lógica, por favor pulsa en [edit] y explica las cosas. Por ejemplo, ¿de qué modo controlas la cantidad de intentos de login, hay una tabla o algo donde eso se controla? Luego pasas al código y explicas qué hace, qué no hace, qué errores da, qué esperas obtener. El código no es tan claro como para que otro se meta a intentar descrifrarlo, explícalo tú y de paso eso te ayudará a entender tu propio problema. Cada vez me convenzo más de que a menudo el mayor problema es no saber explicar el problema.

Comment: Dispense las molestias estimado @A.Cedano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para tratar un caso así debes considerar condicionales que identifiquen de manera única cada escenario posible.

En tu planteamiento, la condicion `IF CONTEO2 = 0` se cumple al menos cuando el usuario no existe y cuando existe con estatus activo

Con base en lo que interpreto de tu requerimiento voy a enumerar las posibilidades para tener una guía al momento de escribir las condiciones:

- Si usuario existe

  - Si usuario esta activo

    - Si contraseña es valida

      - Resultado OK (escenario ideal)
    - Sino (contraseña errada)

      - Leer numero de reintentos
      - Si reintentos supera el tope (8)

        - Resultado NO EXISTE
      - Sino (cantidad de reintentos menor que 8)

        - Incrementar contador de reintentos
  - Sino (usuario inactivo)

    - Falta definir lo que ocurre con el usuario inactivo
- Sino (usuario no existe)

  - Resultado ...

Lo otro será declarar las variables con nombres que tengan un poco más de significado.

El código a continuación es sólo una guía que debe ser completada en algunos casos. No lo pude probar al 100% porque no tengo disponible una instalación de MySQL.

```
/* ... */
BEGIN
/* Los nombres de variables son mejores cuando aportan algún significado */
DECLARE LOGIN_OK, USUARIO_EXISTE, ESTA_ACTIVO, REINTENTOS INT DEFAULT 0;

/* Primero evalúa el escenario ideal (cuando el login tiene exito) */
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO LOGIN_OK FROM INHA_DET_CFGUSUARIOS 
WHERE CUSU_CUSUARIO = PUSU AND CUSU_CCONTRASENIA = PCONTRA AND CUSU_NESTATUSUSUARIO  = 1;

IF LOGIN_OK = 1 THEN
    /* este bloque es una copia del código original en el caso IF CONTEO = 1 */
    SELECT US.CUSU_CUSUARIO AS USUARIO , USUROL.CUSR_NIDROL AS ROL
    FROM INHA_DET_CFGUSUARIOS US
         INNER JOIN INHA_DET_CFGUSUROL USUROL ON USUROL.CUSR_NIDUSUARIO = US.CUSU_NIDUSUARIO
         INNER JOIN INHA_MST_CFGROLES ROLS ON ROLS.CFRO_NIDROL = USUROL.CUSR_NIDROL  
    WHERE US.CUSU_CUSUARIO = PUSU AND US.CUSU_CCONTRASENIA = PCONTRA 
      AND US.CUSU_NESTATUSUSUARIO  = 1; 

    UPDATE INHA_DET_CFGUSUARIOS SET CUSU_NINTENTOSLOGIN = 0 WHERE CUSU_CUSUARIO = PUSU;
    SET PRESULTADO = 'OK';
ELSE
    /* El login NO fue exitoso, son tratados el resto de los casos */

    /* Esta lectura sirve para determinar si el usuario existe y su estatus */
    SELECT COUNT(*), COALESCE(CUSU_NESTATUSUSUARIO, 0) INTO USUARIO_EXISTE, ESTA_ACTIVO 
    FROM INHA_DET_CFGUSUARIOS WHERE CUSU_CUSUARIO = PUSU;

    IF USUARIO_EXISTE = 1 AND ESTA_ACTIVO = 1 THEN
        /* Si llega aquí es porque la contraseña está errada */
        
        /* Leer el número de reintentos */
        SELECT CUSU_NINTENTOSLOGIN INTO REINTENTOS 
        FROM INHA_DET_CFGUSUARIOS WHERE CUSU_CUSUARIO = PUSU;

        IF REINTENTOS >= 8 THEN
            /* Llegó al limite de reintentos */
            SET PRESULTADO = 'NO EXISTE';
            /* completar el código si fuera necesario */
        ELSE
            /* Incrementar el contador de reintentos */
            UPDATE INHA_DET_CFGUSUARIOS SET CUSU_NINTENTOSLOGIN =  CUSU_NINTENTOSLOGIN + 1 
            WHERE CUSU_CUSUARIO = PUSU;
            /* Asignar el valor a PRESULTADO cuando la contaseña está errada, 
               si lo interpreté bien es CONTRASEÑA */
            SET PRESULTADO = 'CONTRASEÑA';  
        END IF

    ELSEIF USUARIO_EXISTE = 1 AND ESTA_ACTIVO = 0 THEN
       /* En la pregunta no hay información de lo que ocurre 
          cuando el usuario EXISTE pero está INACTIVO */
    ELSE
        /* En este punto el usuario NO EXISTE
           no está claro lo que se hace en este caso */
    END IF
END IF
```